Attribute Error when using Pandas datareader for Yahoo
I'm trying to use the pandas data reader package to pull stock price data from yahoo for Tesla stock but it keeps showing - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'.
This is what I inputted:
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

style.use ('ggplot')

start= dt.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
end= dt.datetime(2016,12,31)

df= web.DataReader('TSLA', 'yahoo', start, end)

and it resulted in this:
>>> df= web.DataReader('TSLA', 'yahoo', start, end)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/name/Python learning/Data visualisation and graphing/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 213, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/name/Python learning/Data visualisation and graphing/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py", line 379, in DataReader
    ).read()
      ^^^^^^
  File "/Users/name/Python learning/Data visualisation and graphing/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 253, in read
    df = self._read_one_data(self.url, params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/name/Python learning/Data visualisation and graphing/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas_datareader/yahoo/daily.py", line 152, in _read_one_data
    j = json.loads(re.search(ptrn, resp.text, re.DOTALL).group(1))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

I have seen some threads saying that pandas data reader isn't working anymore with yahoo or that it's due to the new Python version 3.12 but I am pretty unsure. What am I meant to do to get this to work?

data-reader project seems being stalled since 2021 , I won't trust that to read data from anywhere correctly if the data source data format / schema has changed which is most probable . find your data source and write the code to fetch/scrape/load data yourself

This question is similar to: Pandas Error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
